# Is it possible to view the new headless Chrome in a debug window when starting from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, headless

I am trying to load web pages in the new headless Chrome and view them in a debug window. With the old version of headless, this was accomplished by starting it with a remote-debugging-port switch, opening another browser, and navigating to localhost:9222. These steps do not work with the latest version of Chrome headless.

Running Chrome 121 on a Mac under Sonoma 14.2.1. I'm starting an instance of headless Chrome with this command line:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/mycustomprofiledirectory" --headless=new --remote-debugging-port=0
```

This returns the following:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57215/devtools/browser/3c94b6c8-2105-4ad9-8963-morenumbershere
```

Attempting to open the link above in a new Chrome browser gives the following error:

```
Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

I've tried different combinations of startup switches to no avail. Is this still possible?